# Is there anyway that we can get a label value to a Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataview

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 
FROM Book 
INNER JOIN Temp_Order ON Book.Book_ID = Temp_Order.Book_ID 
WHERE (Temp_Order.User_ID = 25) 
AND (CONVERT (nvarchar, Temp_Order.OrderDate, 111) = CONVERT (nvarchar, GETDATE(), 111))
```

In here i want to change my User_ID to get from a label.Text

this Sql Statement is in a DataView. so in the Wizard it not accepting a text box values or anything.

can someone please help me to solve this

Comment: You may want to update your post to also say that you are working in the (VB/C#) .net framework as you are talking about a DataView. Also can you clarify what you want to accomplish? I'm assuming you want to add a filter ability by user_ID that you enter into a text box or something, but its not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you. yes its in c#. i want to show the sum of a certain sql statement in the dataview. 

to that specific SQL statement useridlabel.text is taken as the User_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Never compare date columns by using CONVERT. To compare date only from a date time, use BETWEEN. Better still, use the [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) type for the column instead of DATETIME.

To filter a DataView, filter the query on which is based. Use a parametrized query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 
FROM Book 
INNER JOIN Temp_Order ON Book.Book_ID = Temp_Order.Book_ID 
WHERE (Temp_Order.User_ID = @User_ID) 
AND Temp_Order.OrderDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate;
```

Pass the @User_ID as a parameter to the query: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", Convert.ToInt32(label.Text));`

You can also obtain similar results using LINQ and converting the result to a DataView, see [Filtering with DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669073.aspx).

> In addition to the string-based
>   filtering capabilities DataView  also
>   provides the ability to use LINQ
>   expressions for the filtering
>   criteria. LINQ expressions allow for
>   much more complex and powerful
>   filtering operations than the
>   string-based filtering.

Whatever you do, don't use the DataView.RowFilter property.